# open the pdf in browser using spring and java

Tags: java, pdf, browser, inline, content-disposition

below i am reading the pdf from the data base... and i am trying to open the pdf file in browser... but instead of opening in browser it always downloaded...the code is given below please help me to open the pdf in browser instead of asking for download....

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "account/documents/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadDocument(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("id") String docId)
        throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    int accountId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("ownerAccountId");
    Map<String, String> docMap = DbInteractor.getUploadedDocsByDocId(
            Integer.valueOf(docId), accountId);
    String docName = docMap.get("name");
    String typeName = docMap.get("type");
    String[] fileName = docName.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
    typeName = typeName.replace(" ", "");
    if (typeName.equals("CCD/CCR")) {
        typeName = "CCDorCCR";
    }
    String filename = typeName + docId + "." + fileName[1];
    System.out.println(filename);
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
            Constants.DOCUMENTS_PATH + filename);
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
            "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename="
            + docName);
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

can you  please help me.....

Comment: Try to inspect the actual response header fields in the browser.

Comment: Please consider that the **docName could contain spaces**, this: `filename=\"" + docName + "\""` is much better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change content type so that, your browser recognizes the data. Add this line in your code -

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Also, you can try with `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",  "inline");` with and without attachment property. (As I am not sure and haven't checked it yet. :-))

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried both but its not working.... I used   response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename="
    + docName);

Comment: Try to remove filename = docname .

Answer (score 0):

I removed:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename="+ docName);
```

and added:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: Please consider that the **docName could contain spaces**, this: `filename=\"" + docName + "\""` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using `ResponseEntity<byte[]>`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getExport() {
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    ByteArrayOutputStream boas = null;
    try {
        String inputFile = "files/templates/autodebit.html";
        String outputFile = "files/generated/autodebit_"+filenameDate.format(new Date())+".pdf";

        String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFile)));
        final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
        document.body().select(".DOC_GENERATED_DATE").html(readableDate.format(new Date()));

        renderer.setDocumentFromString(document.html());
        renderer.layout();

        try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(outputFile))) {
            renderer.createPDF(os);
            os.close();

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(outputFile);
            boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, boas);
            stamper.setPageAction(PdfWriter.PAGE_OPEN, new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG), 1); 
            stamper.close();
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReportController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(boas.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Hope it helps!